# Can an iBeacon be used to broadcast sensor door open/close?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

my understanding is that a BLE ibeacon is used as a transmitter and used for location/distance. Is it possible to be used to send a status of a wired up relay (e.g. on/off) to an android/ios bluetooth enable app instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  You would need a circuit that sends a proper on/off voltage to a GPIO pin on your hardware platform, then you would have to write code that reads that GPIO pin and conditionally alters a BLE manufacturer advertisement to change one but in the iBeacon major or minor field to indicate the on/off status.

An OS or Android app could be programmed to behave differently upon detecting this beacon advertisement and reading the on/off bit in the major or minor field.